# Plotting 100 different realizations of the log-normal random variable

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am having trouble with the output figure.

```
pr = pt - plo - 10*gamma*log_base10(d/d0) - x_sigma
```

Given: `pt = 0`, `plo = 55`, `gamma = 4.7`, `d0 = 1`, `sigma = 4.6`.
Here, `sigma` is the standard deviation of the normal random variable `x_sigma`.

I have to take 100 different realizations of the log-normal random variable `x_sigma` for each distance value `d`.

The goal is to plot `pr` vs `d` on a graph.
here is my code, I don't know where I am making the mistake:

```
 Pt = 0;
 Pl0 = 55;
 gamma = 4.7;
 d0 =1;
 d= [1:20:2000]
 x_sigma = lognrnd(0, 4.6, 1, 100)


 Pr = Pt - Pl0 - 10.*gamma.* log10(d/d0) - x_sigma
 figure; plot(d, Pr); hold on;
```

Comment: It's not very clear what the issue is...